# Телеграм бот отвечает репликой из первого хендлера на текст из второго хендлера

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Новичок, пишу телеграм бот на Питоне +PyTelegramBotAPI

Написала метод получения сообщения со связкой "if else", отрабатывает успешно.
Написала еще один метод получения сообщения с другим текстом, а бот все равно отвечает репликой (Скажи кодовую фразу) из первого метода. Как пофиксить?

```
 @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Хочу тестить":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Какой шалун тестер")
    else:
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Скажи кодовую фразу")

      @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
      def get_text_message(message):
          if message.text == "Скажи триста":
              bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я на это не поведусь!")
```

Comment: для начала выправить отступы. А потом подумать - если текст не равен "Хочу тестить", то что произойдет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Хочу тестить":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Какой шалун тестер")
    elif message.text == "Скажи триста":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я на это не поведусь!")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Скажи кодовую фразу")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,получилось!